# What technique do I use to sculpt a viper snake heat sensing holes?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode, brushes

Hello and sorry in advance if the question is too generic. I'm very new to blender, and struggle to finish one of my very first project. I'm trying to sculpt a blue viper snake head (to be precise the top half of it, without the bottom jaw) and the most challenging part are those heat sensing holes located between the eyes and the nostrils. I don't have any reference images but publicly available pictures from internet: [image]
[image]

When how are such parts made. I mostly start with "digging" the face inward with use of "Draw" / sometimes "Draw Sharp" brushes, but no matter how i do that, the holes become too smooth after a couple of remeshing iterations (I start with low-poly UV-sphere, and increase number of polygons steadily):

[image]
[image]
[image]

What kind of technique is recommended for such stuff? I'm not exactly sure I can find appropriate set of brushes to sculpt a scale-ish creature properly.

Thanks in advance for any piece of advice!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to sharp with the *Smooth* brush inverted (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to invert the effect):

[image]